# Python-style classmethod for C#?

Tags: c#, python, class-method

Is there a way to do what `classmethod` does in Python in C#?

That is, a static function that would get a Type object as an (implicit) parameter according to whichever subclass it's used from.

An example of what I want, approximately, is

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        print "Would instantiate a new %r with ID %d."%(cls, id)

class Puppy(Base):
    pass

class Kitten(Base):
    pass

p = Puppy.get(1)
k = Kitten.get(1)
```

the expected output being

```
Would instantiate a new <class __main__.Puppy at 0x403533ec> with ID 1.
Would instantiate a new <class __main__.Kitten at 0x4035341c> with ID 1.
```

[(same code on codepad here.)](http://codepad.org/yTPLcpys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you *could* write something like this:

```
class Base
{
    public static T Get<T>(int id)
        where T : Base, new()
    {
        return new T() { ID = id };
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could write `var p = Base.Get<Puppy>(10)`. Or, if you were feeling masochistic, you could write `Puppy.Get<Puppy>(10)` or even `Kitty.Get<Puppy>` ;) In all cases, you have to pass in the type explicitly, not implicitly.

Alternatively, this works too:

```
class Base<T> where T : Base<T>, new()
{
    public static T Get(int id)
    {
        return new T() { ID = id };
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}

class Puppy : Base<Puppy>
{
}

class Kitten : Base<Kitten>
{
}
```

You still need to pass the type back up to the base class, which allows you to write `Puppy.Get(10)` as expected.

But still, is there a reason to write it like that when `var p = new Puppy(10)` is just as concise and more idiomatic? Probably not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to take a look at generics.

Guide from MSFT:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, you either want generics or virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to class methods in Object Pascal. (a .Net implementation would be RemObject's oxygene).

However, while class references and thus virtual class methods or seemingly static methods which can kinda access some class-level state are nice in there original platform, I don't think they make much sense for .Net or C#.

I used to also program in Oxygene for several years, and I never needed class references.

Not because I didn't know how to use them. In the "original" ObjectPascal platform, native Delphi, I used them **all** the time.
But because .Net and the BCL have no real support for them, so you do not have any advantages by using them. Whereas platforms like python or native Delphi do support them in their libraries.

You obviously do not want a static method, what you want is something that can have state and/or supports inheritance. So either factories, or in your case a constructor might be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because C# is statically compiled, a call to `Puppy.get()` is resolved at compile time, eg. it's known to point to `Base.get()` and that means that the generated CIL (Common Intermediate Language) will have a call instruction to `Base.get()`:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0002:  call       void Base::get(int32)
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ret
}
```